# How can I figure out if my computers cores use shared or distributed memory?

Tags: linux, osx, cpu

I have a computer that has a Intel® Core™ i7-4558U Processor. It's got 2 cores but I don't know if they use shared or distributed memory. How can I find out?

Answer (score 1):

The cores in single-socket systems like yours have equal access to memory, through a shared memory controller. They also share their outermost cache ([4 MiB in your case](https://ark.intel.com/products/75992/Intel-Core-i7-4558U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz?q=4558U)). Each core has its own layer 1 and 2 caches ([64 KiB and 256 KiB per core respectively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_%28microarchitecture%29)).

On Intel x86-compatible systems, you only run into NUMA ([non-uniform memory access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access)) on larger systems with multiple sockets (technically, higher-end server CPUs with ten cores or more can also *simulate* NUMA, but that doesn’t change their real memory architecture). On such systems, each CPU socket controls a set of memory banks, and access to memory takes longer if the code performing the access is running on a CPU which isn’t the one controlling the memory in question. However in most x86-style systems, all of memory is still shared — every CPU can access every byte of RAM.

The vast, vast majority of x86-based systems are shared memory systems, even when they are NUMA systems; [distributed memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_memory) is highly unusual, and on x86 you’re likely to encounter it only in super-computers.

To find all this out, you would need to investigate your system’s architecture, for example by reading detailed reviews such as [AnandTech’s](https://www.anandtech.com/show/6355/intels-haswell-architecture), or even Intel’s datasheets. It seems to be considered such “common knowledge” that it tends not to be mentioned...